# Display keybindings by 2nd letter

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I like to know, which keys are bounded by 2nd letter in Emacs. For example, I like to find all keybindings that has 2nd letter 'p'.  It should return me C-x p, C-c p, C-h p  etc.

Something  like  "C-h b by 2nd letter",  would be very useful.

Comment: Would the search option suffice or are you looking for a specific key to only show you the key bindings that have a "2nd letter"?

Comment: Some lisp code should do. So I can customize it my way and use it.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^\S-+ b` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: +1 This only works for the current major / minor mode combo, though, not globally.